# How to design Reports in Devexpress C#. And is it possible to design report without Dataset in Devexpress c#.net

Tags: c#, devexpress, report

How to design Reports in Devexpress C#. And is it possible to design report without Dataset in Devexpress c#.net.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can design report without DataSet but using SqlDataSource instead. Even you can design report even without any datasource - it will be a static document.
also you can read the [official documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4257) for more details.
Do you have any other specific issues while designing your report?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the [Reporting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2162) section of DevExpress documentation.

This contains information for DevExpress Reporting, which let you know that how to create reports and reporting applications targeted at the WinForms, ASP.NET and WPF platforms.

**Que: How to design Reports in Devexpress C#?**

> The DevExpress Reporting suite provides a feature-rich [report designer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/CustomDocument4256.aspx)
>   to create reports at Visual Studio design time.
>
> The created reports are platform-agnostic and can be published later
>   on any of the supported platforms that include WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET
>   and ASP.NET MVC.

**Que:is it possible to design report without Dataset?**

> Yes, Go through [Providing Data to Reports](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2594) section to know the
>   various data source type can be used with reports.

Hope this help.